# How do I call a function defined in a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I have a function defined in a javascript variable.  How do I call that function within a javascript function?

```
function clear_viewer() {
     var stop_function = "jwplayer.stop();";
     // call stop_function here
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you storing the function as string, simply call jwplayer().stop()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function clear_viewer() {
     var stop_function = "jwplayer.stop();";
     eval(stop_function);
}
```

You shouldn't do this though, `eval` should be avoided if at all possible.  Instead you should do something more like this, which creates a function directly for later execution.

```
function clear_viewer() {
     var stop_function = function() {
       jwplayer.stop();
     };
     stop_function();
}
```

Comment: Why suggest `eval()` and then tell the OP they shouldn't do this?

Comment: Because we don't have the full story here.  This may be a contrived example, but based on a real world problem where he gets a string of JS from somewhere he can't control, and wants to execute it.  If that's the case, `eval` is the only real option.  Note how I said "`eval` should be avoided _if at all possible_".  Sometimes the answer to a question is "here's the way you should do it, but here is the less optimal way you might have to do it".  There are very few "right" answers in programming, and more often than not the answer is "it depends".

Comment: That did not do it.  This did not call the function and did not continue to execute the other statements after `eval(stop_function)`.

Comment: @user823527 It definitely works, given what code you have posted so far: http://jsfiddle.net/7AfCc/ Your problem lies elsewhere... Check the JS condole for errors.

Comment: OK.  It does work.  I had to provide the object ID with that function call.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Could always go with the 'all evil' `eval()`:

```
eval(stop_function);
```

Obviously you need to be very careful when using eval so that you don't wind up executing malicious code accidentally. Another option would be to turn stop_function into an anonymous function that executes your code:

```
var stop_function = function(){
    jwplayer.stop();
};

stop_function();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function clear_viewer() {
     var stop_function = function(){ jwplayer.stop();};
     stop_function();
}
```

Comment: It would make more sense to create the stopFunction() outside the clear_viewer. Looking at this "simple" sample, declaring and executing it as function in the same method shouldnt be needed.

Comment: I agree, but it's a literal answer to the OP's question not an architectural recommendation. That's not what he asked.

Comment: Agree, my comment was meant for the OP.